How to show that an AR(1) process with Gaussian errors is ergodic?
(Repost of this thread, as I believe that the answer may be wrong.)
An $\text{AR}(1)$ model with Gaussian errors takes the form below:
$$x_t = \rho x_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$$ where $\epsilon_t$ are IID Gaussians, i.e. $\epsilon_t \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$
Can we show that $x_t$ is ergodic?
A solution is provided in an answer in this thread, but I am having trouble understanding it. Specifically, they "note that
$$x_t = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \rho^k \epsilon_{t-k} = f(\epsilon_t, \epsilon_{t-1, \ldots}) \tag{1} \label{1}$$ is the measurable image of an $L^2$ IID (hence ergodic) sequence; since ergodicity is preserved under measurable maps (cf. Billingsley Theorem 36.4), $x_t$ is ergodic."
However, I am confused:
i) why should $\eqref{1}$ hold in the first place? It seems that
$$
x_t = \rho^t\epsilon_0 + \cdots + \epsilon_t = \sum_{k=0}^t \rho^k \epsilon_{t-k} \tag{2} \label{2}
$$
should hold true, but $\eqref{1}$ adds on the negative-indexed $\epsilon_{-1}, \epsilon_{-2}, \cdots$ terms as well. Since we assume the $\epsilon_{i}$ are IID, in particular, $\eqref{1}$ seems different from $\eqref{2}$.
Have been struggling for quite a while :(, so any insight would be deeply appreciated.

If I am not missing anything, your equation (1) holds if we assume the initial condition $x_0 = 0$. Billingsley's initial condition is $x_0 = \sum_{k \geq 0} \rho^k \epsilon_{-k}$. In a way, you are assuming that the process started at $t = 0$, whereas Billingsley assumed that the process has been running forever -- the latter has the advantage of been stationary. In other words, the difference lies in the initial condition choice. The latter, further allows him to resort to Thm. 36.4.

Hi Augusto Santos! x_0 = 0, thanks for the catch :) I am still a bit confused:
i) I can see how (2) should follow from x_0 = 0, but it seems that (1) should only hold if $x_0 = \sum_{k \geq 0} p^k\epsilon_{-k}$. Doesn't that mean the process in Billingsley is distinct from my process?                                                                             ii) Consequently, does that mean the proof in Billingsley won't work if $x_0 = 0$? Or is there some version of the proof for a one-sided process?                                    Any insight would be extremely appreciated :))

@AugustoSantos Oops, forgot to tag your name in the comment :))

Hi @Stephen: In a measure space $(S,\mathcal{F}, \mu)$, a transformation $T,:S \rightarrow S$ is ergodic if it is measure preserving, i.e., $\mu(T^{-1} F) = \mu(F)$ for any $F \in \mathcal{F}$ and the invariant sets are $\mu$-null sets or full sets. In your context, the ambient is the space of sample paths $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$; the measure is the distribution of the process $X$; and the transformation $T$ is the "shift". If the AR(1) process is initialized as in Billingsley, then it is ergodic (in the sense referred to before). The good news in this case is that you have equation (36.27)

As for the process with $x(0) = 0$ initialization, it is not shift invariant (therefore not strictly ergodic, w.r.t. the shift transformation unless I am missing something), but it converges to the process initialized as in Billingsley as $t\rightarrow \infty$ and in this regard, you could still resort to equation (36.27). As soon as I am able, I could place a full answer (if nobody else does).

@AugustoSantos Yup, you addressed it perfectly -- I was confused if the $x(0) = 0$ initialization is shift invariant (which it is not). However, you say there is still a way to apply equation (36.27)? Would be extremely fascinating :)

I believe that the full version of the Ergodic Theorem does not hold for the process initialized at the origin. Some weaker versions hold under a natural coupling, e.g., mean ergodicity as in my answer below. The stronger the version that we demand, the more we should regularity and constraints we should place on the moments of the process as well as on the map $f$. That is my take on it.

You’ll want $| \rho | < 1$ for stationary.

@BrianBorchers: $\left|\rho\right|<1$ renders the dynamical system stable and it is assumed throughout. Under $\left|\rho\right|<1$ the system is asymptotically stationary: If I am not failing on anything, the distribution of $x_t$ converges to the invariant distribution (the global attractor in the distribution space). However, the initial condition is important to grant stationarity of the process (hence, shift invariance and ergodicity in Billingsley's sense).

If I am not missing anything, and complementing the comments, please find below my reading of the problem so far.
Remark 1. As referred to in the comments, the process $\left(\widetilde{x}_n\right)$ with initial condition $\widetilde{x}_0 = 0$ is not shift invariant -- hence it is not Ergodic in the sense of Billingsley/Birkhoff/etc. for the shift transformation. However, it can be approximated by $\left(x_n\right)$ asymptotically. This yields some weaker form of ergodicity as, e.g., "mean ergodicity".
Coupling. Assume that both processes $\left(x_n\right)$ and $\left(\widetilde{x}_n\right)$ are driven by the same noise process $\left(\epsilon_n\right)$.
First, remark that
$$ \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{m=0}^{n} x_m -\widetilde{x}_m = \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{m=0}^{n} \sum_{k \geq m} \rho^k \epsilon_{m-k} \overset{\mathbb{P}}\longrightarrow 0.\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, (\star)$$
Indeed,
$${\sf Var}\left(\sum_{k \geq m} \rho^k \epsilon_{m-k}\right)=\frac{\rho^{m+1}}{1-\rho}\sigma^2,$$
and therefore,
$${\sf Var}\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{m=0}^{n}\sum_{k \geq m} \rho^k \epsilon_{m-k}\right) \leq \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{m=0}^{n}\frac{\rho^{m+1}}{1-\rho}\sigma^2\longrightarrow 0.$$
$(\star)$ now follows in view of Chebyshev (or Chernoff).
Therefore,
$$\frac{1}{n+1} \sum_{m=0}^n \widetilde{x}_m = \frac{1}{n+1} \sum_{m=0}^n \widetilde{x}_m-x_m + x_m \overset{\mathbb{P}}\longrightarrow 0,$$
where the convergence holds in view of $(\star)$ and the Ergodic Theorem applied to $\left(x_n\right)$.
Remark 2. I believe that stronger Ergodic results hold for $\left(\widetilde{x}_n\right)$ contingent on constraints on the moments of $\left(\widetilde{x}_n\right)$ (that determine how fast it mixes into $(x_n)$) and regularity assumptions on the map $f$ in the ergodic Theorem of Billingsley.
